# How to properly handle child routes in react-router (routing works, but URL grows with each click)

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am in the process of learning how to use react-router. My routing is working correctly, meaning that I get the views I need as I click the appropriate links. I have a view that has nested/child routes. Clicking on these child links does take me to the appropriate view, but it doesn't update the browser's URL as I would like.

I start with the the IndexRoute for the view. The browser's URL starts looking like this, which is what I want:

`http://localhost:3000/administration`

As I click the different child routes, it keeps appending the child route's path onto the URL, so that after a couple of clicks the browser's URL ends up looking soemthing like this:

`http://localhost:3000/administration/administration/administration/administration/administration/administration/administration/administration/company-goals`

When what I want is the browser's URL to be this:

`http://localhost:3000/administration/company-goals`

I have a route structure set up like the following:

`<Route path="/" component={HomePage}>
    <IndexRoute component={HomeView} />
    <Route path="budgets" component={BudgetView} />
    <Route path="administration" component={adminViews.Administration}>
        <IndexRoute component={adminViews.Home} />
        <Route path="department-budgets" component={adminViews.DepartmentBudgets} />
        <Route path="price-list" component={adminViews.PriceList} />
        <Route path="company-goals" component={adminViews.CompanyGoals} />
    </Route>
</Route>`

The Administration view has a tabbed navigation, with a tab for each of the Administration's view's child routes.

I am changing the route when the user clicks on a tab with a function like the following:

`selectedTab( tab ) {
    const menu = menuItems.find((item) => {
        return item.payload === tab.value;
    });
    history.pushState(null, menu.uriPath);
}`

And the uriPath for each of the routes is defined as follows:

`menuItems = [
    {
        payload : '1',
        text    : 'Home',
        uriPath : 'administration'
    },
    {
        payload : '2',
        text    : 'Department Budgets',
        uriPath : 'administration/department-budgets'
    },
    {
        payload : '3',
        text    : 'Price List',
        uriPath : 'administration/price-list'
    },
    {
        payload : '4',
        text    : 'Company Goals',
        uriPath : 'administration/company-goals'
    }
];`

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I feel like I'm missing something very basic, but I haven't been able to identify what I'm doing wrong.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put a `/` at the beginning of your `uriPath`s.

Comment: Okay that fixed it! Thank you. Now the question is why did that fix it?

Comment: It's just a relative vs absolute path. The same reason `<a href="blah">` and `<a href="/blah">` will go different places if you're not at the root.